# If the admin doesn't set the ssh service port on default 22, how can I find the port that he set?

Tags: linux, networking, security, ssh

If the admin doesn't set the ssh service port on default 22, how can I find the port that he set? Trust me I don't plan to doing bad things. I am just curious!

```
update: The ssh service port is on 521. I can be sure. Because i can use ssh login via 521.
nmap addresshided -sV
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-09-30 09:38 CST
Nmap scan report for addresshided
Host is up (0.0052s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
23/tcp  closed telnet
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp closed https
631/tcp closed ipp

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.45 seconds
```

I think i need to study nmap further. Thank you for all the reply. :-)

Comment: this comes up blank? >nmap -P0 -p521 ip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nmap [ip] -sV
```

or, if on the local machine:

```
netstat -tlp | grep -i ssh
```

Comment: Good answer, but why the backticks?  what's the output being used for?  Typing this as shown will give you odd errors.  I know this is nit-picky, but the cmd line IS picky... especially since naive people will type it exactly as shown, just as they've been taught since day one.

Comment: @Sirex, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, send them an email and ask.

Comment: +1. Simple solution to a simple problem. Unauthorized port scans are against terms and conditions within certain networks too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this easy to use online tool [port scanner](http://en.dnstools.ch/port-scan.html).
It will list out all the open ports and what are the configured for.
---EDIT--
You could use the following commands :

> `$ lsof`
>   This lists out all you open ports
>   `$ netstat -nan | grep 22`
>   This will give you detail of theport specified

Comment: 22 "SSH"-Port is closed. But the ssh service is on 521. I am sure it is open. Because i can login.

Comment: @LouXiu so problem solved, isn't it? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @woliveirajr, =.=  No... that port scanner's result is not even include 512. I know the ssh service is on 512. lsof and netstat works if i login the server. But if i am not in the server. How can i do it?

Comment: have you tried my answer, using some app to do that ?

Comment: @woliveirajr, I tried that port scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in a terminal:

```
lsof | grep IPv4 | grep ssh
```

1. `lsof`will list all open files and ports.
2. `grep IPv4` weeds out everything except open IP sockets
3. `grep ssh` shows only lines with ssh.

If you look through the results, you should be able to find which ports are in use by the ssh process.

Comment: This will only work locally, correct? If so, I suppose one couldn't necessarily open the ssh config read-only.. Interesting answer. :)

Comment: @Doc: Ha, you're right. It didn't even occur to me the asker might not be _on_ the computer he's asking about.